# Discovered - all ipv6 ports are open

Tags: ipv6

I am experimenting and exploring `IPv6` possibilities. I turned on `IPv6` on my Android phone (`APN IPv4 / IPv6`) and the desktop got an `IPv6` address through the phone's hotspot `DHCP` server. The address is associated with the ISP of the mobile operator. Doing a routine test to this address

```
# nmap -v -A -6 xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```

I found out that 975 ports out of 1000 are open. `Ufw` is running and `IPv6` is enabled in the configuration.

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.xxx.xxx/24 metric 1024 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 2831sec preferred_lft 2831sec
    inet6 xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3242sec preferred_lft 3242sec
    inet6 yyyy::yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: wireguard: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet6 zzzz:zzzz:zzzz:zzzz:zzzz:zzzz:zzzz:zzzz/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I turn off the `wireguard` link created by `wg-quick`, everything is normal, no ports open at `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx`.

On the Android phone, when I use connection of the same Wireguard profile, the `IPv6` address ports of the `wlan0` link are all closed except for `TCP 53`.

1. Should I be worried?
2. Why do these ports open when running the wg-quick@wireguard profile?
3. How to close them?

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. `open` is a misdiagnosis, probably caused by your wireguard link not relying all ICMP messages
3. Nothing to be done here.

Comment: Thanks ! I found that I can test any IP address, even non-existent ones, and `nmap` still finds all ports open. Is there any other reliable tool to test `IPv6`?!

Comment: Not quite sure what you *want* to test there. "open" is a statement on what you observe how the TCP/IP stack on the other end behaves. Is there something wrong with it? I think you're interpreting too much into "open".